# Input does not allow changing the value in the change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to modify the input values ​​in the change event and it does not allow me this is my code

```
<Input type="text" name="traMake" required value={truckEdit.tra.traMake} onChange={ingresarValoresMemoria} id="idMake" placeholder="Campo obligatorio" />
```

but when modifying the value by value = {truckEdit.tra.traMake} if it lets me modify it but my entity has this structure

```
const [truckEdit,setTruckEdit]= useState({
        truId           :'',
        driId           : '',
        TruExdate       : '',
        TruAddress      : '',
        tra             : ({
            traMake     : '',
            traOption   : '',
            traUnit     : '',
        }),
        TraUnit         : '',
        TraOption       : '',
        truDocurl       : '' 
    });
```

is there any way to keep the structure and be able to avoid input blocking

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use Object Spread.

See the below code

```js
  function handleTraMakeChange(newValue) {
    setTruckEdit({
      ...truckEdit,
      tra: {
        ...truckEdit.tra,
        ["traMake"]: newValue
      }
    });
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="text"
        name="traMake"
        required
        value={truckEdit.tra.traMake}
        onChange={(e) => handleTraMakeChange(e.target.value)}
        id="idMake"
        placeholder="Campo obligatorio"
      />
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: tra             : ({
            traMake     : '',
            traOption   : '',
            traUnit     : '',
        }),    I would like to change the value of all when writing

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `truckEdit.tra.traMake` value onChange. You can do that by

```
<Input type="text" name="traMake" required value={truckEdit.tra.traMake} onChange={(e)=>{ingresarValoresMemoria(e, 'traMake')}} id="idMake" placeholder="Campo obligatorio" />
```

```
const ingresarValoresMemoria = (e, fieldName) => {
    setTruckEdit({
      ...truckEdit,
      tra: {
        ...truckEdit.tra,
        [fieldName]: e.target.value
      }
    });
  };
```

For other fields inside `tra` you'll need different inputs and you'll need to pass appropriate `fieldName` on their `onChange` functions.

[Code Sand Box Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-lake-qbkd2?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: but I want to change all the ones I have inside tra: ({
            traMake: '',
            traOption: '',
            traUnit: '',
        }),

Comment: before i had this   const {name, value} = e.target;
        setTruckEdit(anterior=>({
            ...anterior, 
            [name]: value 
        }))

Comment: @RollerFernandez ```traOption``` and ```traUnit``` must be in different input fields right? You can pass e and field name as well. I'll update the code.

Comment: Keep blocking the input inputs applying this solution

Comment: @RollerFernandez I have setup a small demo and inputs aren't blocking. Take a look https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-lake-qbkd2?file=/src/App.js